# How to create a settings object in Swift

Tags: swift, struct, notificationcenter

I'm attempting to create an object in Swift-3 that will hold a variety of basic user-settings which can be easily accessed throughout the application. I currently have this setup as a struct called `PTSettings`. It is implemented like so:

```
struct PTSettings {
    static var aUserSettings: String()
}
```

Which can be accessed easily around the application like so: `PTSettings.aUserSetting = "Foo"`

What I am struggling with here is that I'd like this struct to observe the UIScreen notifications from `NotificationCenter`. When a screen connects `PTSettings` initializes the external screen, assigns a view to it, shows a banner to let the user know etc...

I am familiar with doing all of these tasks on UIViewController; however I am not proficient in utilizing structs. My hope is that when the application loads, the struct will be initialized and in that init will being observing `NotificationCenter` while also checking to see if there was a screen connected before the application was loaded.

Below is what I currently have.

```
/// Struct containing various user-generate data such as color, messages and other settings.
struct PTSettings {


    // External UI
    //
    static var externalScreen: UIScreen!
    //
    static var externalWindow: UIWindow!
    //
    static var extDisplay: PTExternalDisplayVC?


    init () {
        // Receive notifications if a screen is connected or disconnected
        //
        let center = NotificationCenter.default
        center.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(PTSettings.handleScreenDidConnectNotification(notification:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIScreenDidConnect, object: nil)
        center.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(PTSettings.handleScreenDidDisconnectNotification(notification:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIScreenDidDisconnect, object: nil)
        center.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(PTSettings.handleScreenModeDidChangeNotification), name: NSNotification.Name.UIScreenModeDidChange, object: nil)
    }




    // MARK: External Displays
    //
    static func initializeExternalScreen(externalScreen:UIScreen) {
        self.externalScreen = externalScreen

        externalScreen.overscanCompensation = UIScreenOverscanCompensation(rawValue: 3)!

        // Create a new window sized to the external screen's bounds
        self.externalWindow = UIWindow(frame: self.externalScreen.bounds)

        // Assign screen object to screen property of the new window
        self.externalWindow.screen = externalScreen

        // Load the clock view
        let viewForExternalScreen = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ExternalDisplay") as! PTExternalDisplayVC
        viewForExternalScreen.view.frame = self.externalWindow.frame

        // Add the view to the window
        self.externalWindow.addSubview(viewForExternalScreen.view)

        // Create a reference to the viewForExternalScreen
        self.extDisplay = viewForExternalScreen

        // Make the window visible
        self.externalWindow.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }
    //
    static func handleScreenDidConnectNotification (notification:Notification) {
        if let screen = notification.object as? UIScreen {
            initializeExternalScreen(externalScreen: screen)
        }
    }
    //
    static func handleScreenDidDisconnectNotification (notification:Notification) {
        if externalWindow != nil {
            externalWindow.isHidden = true
            externalWindow = nil
            displayConnectedLabel.text = "No Display"
            displayConnectedLabel.textColor = CustomColors.Red.color
            JSSAlertView().warning(self, title: "External Display Disconnected.")
        }
    }
    //
    static func handleScreenModeDidChangeNotification () {
        let screen = UIScreen.screens[1]
        initializeExternalScreen(externalScreen: screen)
    }

}
```

The compiler is complaining for each addition of observers in the `init()` method something like this:

*Argument of '#selector' refers to static method 'handleScreenDidConnectNotification(notification:)' that is not exposed to Objective-C*

However when adding `@objc` before the methods, it then complains:

*@objc can only be used with members of classes, @objc protocols and concrete extensions of classes.*

How can I go about achieving the desired result, and am I just totally off in this approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> am I just totally off in this approach

You are indeed totally off. Distinguish Objective-C (and Cocoa) from Swift. Swift structs are a purely Swift feature. You are trying to use a Cocoa feature, namely calling into a method via a *selector*, with a Swift feature, a struct. You can't do that. A Swift struct lacks the Objective-C introspection features that allow selectors to work. That is why you can make a selector only for a method of an Objective-C class, i.e. a *class* that *inherits from NSObject* (as you have done in the past).

However, there's [another form](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsnotificationcenter/1411723-addobserverforname) of adding a notification center observer, where you use a trailing closure / function, not a selector. You might try that instead (though I don't guarantee anything).